# I am importing local images then exporting them to be rendered with .map() but they aren't loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make an Image slider for a web app I am working on, but the images don't seem to be loading / displaying when I use local images, if I add the source as a link, it works fine.

Here are the 3 components I have so far:

**Component 1:** *The one that "renders" everything*

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/MyWork.css'

import { MyWorkTemplate } from './MyWorkTemplate'

function MyWork() {
  return (
    <section>
      <div>
          <MyWorkTemplate/>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default MyWork
```

**Component 2:** *Where my images are created*

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { ImageSliderInfo } from './ImageSliderInfo'
import '../styles/MyWorkTemplate.css'

import {FaArrowCircleRight, FaArrowCircleLeft} from 'react-icons/fa'


export const MyWorkTemplate = () => {

    const length = ImageSliderInfo.length;

    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
    
    const nextImage = () => {
        setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1)
    }

    const previousImage = () => {
        setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1 )
    }

    if(!Array.isArray(ImageSliderInfo) || length <= 0){
        return null
    }

  return (
    <div className='imageSliderContainer'>
        <FaArrowCircleRight className='rightArrow' onClick={nextImage}/>
        <FaArrowCircleLeft className='leftArrow' onClick={previousImage}/>
        {ImageSliderInfo.map((image, index, key) => {
            return (
                <div key={key.imageKey} className={index === current ? 'image active' : 'image'} >
                    {index === current && (<img src={image.image} alt='travel' className='imageSrc'/>)}
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>
)
}
```

**Finally, Component 3:** *Where the info of the images are stored*

```
import img1 from '../assets/myworkphotos/img1.jpg'
import img1 from '../assets/myworkphotos/img2.jpg'


export const ImageSliderInfo = [
    {
      imageKey : '1546768292',
      image: {img1}
    },
    {
      imageKey : '2414950165',
      image: {img2}
    }
]
```

This is what I have so far, and as mentioned above, whenever I use a link as the `image:` value in the 3rd component, it works fine.

I know it's not any of the paths the issue. I also tried using: `require({img1})`, which worked for like a second before throwing so many errors and warnings to the point I had to restart the entire project (I have no idea what happened).

I've searched online and tried a few things but ultimately haven't found the answer to anything yet.

Comment: _(For the "bonus", see https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html. `key`, the third argument to `.map`'s callback, is **the array itself**, so `key.imageKey` is undefined.)_

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. So how could I store the key inside of the 3rd component without throwing an error if I am just passing the array itself?

Comment: Access it on the image (first argument) instead of the array (third argument). Also your main issue is just a typo - `{img1}` is shorthand for `{ img1: img1 }`; `image.image` is an **object**, not a string.

Comment: Well, I'll be dammed !! Removing the ```{}``` from ```{img1}``` now displays the image!! Thank you!! However, instead of ```key={key.imageKey}```, I removed the ```imageKey``` property and wrote ```key={image.imageKey}``` but it is still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
  const ImageSliderInfo = [
{
  imageKey: "1546768292",
  image: `${img1}`,
  alt: "Firts Pic"
},
{
  imageKey: "2414950165",
  image: `${img2}`,
  alt: "Second Pic"
}
```

];

and the CodeSand is here ==> [LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-flower-izvt3k?file=/src/index.jsx:225-438)